# Verifying AWS S3 vs Minio Checksum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

Why AWS S3 when uploading multipart with checksum, the `CompleteMultipart` returns something with `-2` suffix (or probably because I only upload with 2 parts?)

something like `Rrdr4Q==-2`

while in minio it only `Rrdr4Q==`

and I'm sure that later is the valid one.

other checksum of uploading the same file in 2 parts:

```
ETag: dbfdb8aec67c188e2736683651b9226b-2
sha256: W8BHackgomgXOcJes28P1UUzy3Di1XDdp19bqW6/ZqE=-2
sha1: lYKjtVnVFvsqC2m1Mut3AJGod7g=-2
crc32: MU95sw==-2
```

[image: checksum]

Comment: In S3, with multipart uploads, the digest is not the digest of the object, but rather the [digest of the digests of each part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html#large-object-checksums) with the count appended.  If Minio isn't doing this, it's no behaving the same.

Comment: whoa, I just know this, nice info @AnonCoward

Comment: MinIO does return digest-of-digests, but does not append the part count when returned. When we implemented this neither did AWS - and seems like they haven't documented this either.